# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '______' to data type int

Tags: sql-server

```
USE MASTER
GO
CREATE DATABASE db_movies;
GO
USE db_movies;
GO

CREATE TABLE tbl_movies 
(
    movie_id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY (1,1),
    movie_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO tbl_movies (movie_name)
VALUES ('Jurassic Park'), ('Star Wars'), ('Blade Runner');

CREATE TABLE tbl_genre 
(
    genre_id INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY (100,1),
    genre_name VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO tbl_genre (genre_name)
VALUES ('Sci-Fi'), ('Thriller'), ('Horror');

CREATE TABLE tbl_movielist 
(
    MovieID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL IDENTITY (1000,1),
    MovieName VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
    Movie_identification INT NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT fk_movie_id 
            FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tbl_movies(movie_id) 
                 ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    Genre_identification INT NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT fk_genre_id 
            FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES tbl_genre(genre_id) 
                 ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE,
    rating FLOAT(3) NOT NULL, 
);

INSERT INTO tbl_movielist (MovieName, Movie_identification, Genre_identification, rating)
VALUES ('Sandlot', 10, 109, 7.80),
       ('Knives Out', 11, 110, 7.90),
       ('The Notebook', 12, 111, 7.80);

INSERT INTO tbl_genre (genre_name)
VALUES ('Comedy'), ('Mystery'), ('Drama');

INSERT INTO tbl_movies(movie_name)
VALUES ('Sandlot'), ('Knives Out'), ('The Notebook');

SELECT * FROM tbl_genre;
SELECT * FROM tbl_movies;
SELECT * FROM tbl_movielist;

SELECT * 
FROM tbl_movies
INNER JOIN tbl_genre ON CONVERT(int, tbl_genre.genre_id) = tbl_movies.movie_name;
```

I have created a database and for some reason on my final two lines, where I am using the INNER JOIN statement it says "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Jurassic Park' to data type int. Now I have tried using the CAST function and CONVERT function, as well as changing the tbl and attributes I wanted to INNER JOIN. It either says the error message above, or when I do get no error message and it prints a table, there is no data in the tables. Can not figure out why, I am pretty new to SQL.

Comment: `genre_id` is defined as an INT. Why are you converting it to an INT?  (`convert(int,tbl_genre.genre_id)`), and why are you comparing this INT to a `movie_name`?

Comment: How would anyone which genre a movie has?   The table `movie` only contains 2 fields: `move_id` and `movie_name`...     see: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9c932e14601db695a160e7abac9c56ee

Comment: I suggest you change your schema. There appears to be little difference between Movie and MovieList. You probably do want some sort of rating table but it is not clear what "rating" means in your model And why is "rating" defined as float? You need to more clearly define your entities (tables), what they actually represent in the system you are attempting to model, and what the attributes of those entities are along with the appropriate datatype.

Comment: Looking at your schema I see some pretty big challenges. The naming is pretty ambiguous but that is your preference. Also you really should avoid prefixes like tbl_. They provide no benefit and will drive you crazy in the long run. The design issues are that a given movie can have one and only one genre. Also you have made a 1:1 relationship between movielist and movie. This should be three tables in my opinion. Movie, Genre, MovieGenre. That way a movie can be listed under multiple genres.

Comment: You also have the movie name in two tables. This should never happen. You want to store that value once so you have a single point of truth. Otherwise you don't know which one is correct, or you have to always update two tables instead of one.